# How can I enter a code into a comment to somebody's answer?

Tags: discussion, formatting

The question is completely formulated in the title. It is about formatting of the comments here, rather than the Mathematica output, however.

Comment: Do you mean a code block?

Comment: @Michael, yes a code expression, that may be short.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I misunderstand your question, but why don't you use *inline code* which is marked by a beginning and ending backtick? To make `Integrate[x,x]` you just have to type `` `Integrate[x,x]` ``.

There is a [Formatting help page](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) with specific instructions for comments.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I have included your link into my answer.

Comment: Thank you it helps